# Kafka consumer group spending lot of time in rebalancing

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am creating a Platform using Kafka and python, where consumers are ML models, I am trying to forward the request to this ML models, but most of the time the consumer groups are rebalancing. I have a few questions:

1. It is better to give the consumers an ID to reduce the rebalance time, right?
2. If the consumers logically are separated and consume different topics, is it better to put them in separate consumer groups?
3. How can I reduce rebalancing time when starting the system?
   I am modifying the parameter group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms in server.properties, are there rules to change this? Also when I create the consumers, do you suggest that I change the heartbeat_interval_ms and the session_timeout_ms? How?

Answer (score 1):

> better to give the consumers an ID to reduce the rebalance time

IDs don't affect consumer timeouts

> better to put them in separate consumer groups

Depends on your use-case. Separate groups will track topic offsets uniquely. You can consume multiple topics per group, but if one topic has a lot more data than another, then you may not be processing as fast as you want. In that case, you can run multiple processes/treads per group and/or create new groups.

> I am modifying the parameter group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms in server.properties, are there rules to change this?

Not that I know of. You'll need to restart the cluster to modify this, though.

> do you suggest that I change the heartbeat_interval_ms and the session_timeout_ms?

Assuming your consumers are rebalancing from "doing too much", then yes.

> How?

They are parameters to [`KafkaConsumer`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html) constructor...

You may also want to try increasing `max_poll_interval_ms`

Comment: Thank you very much, maybe I was not so clear about the heartbeat_interval_ms and session_timeout_ms: I know that they are parameters of the KafkaConsumer constructor, but is there a rule on how to set them, in the sense of which value to give?

Comment: You'll need to time your current processing logic and see how long it takes, at most. Then maybe give it a 10% upper buffer. Otherwise, if you used average time, for example, then high-load will still exceed that value

Comment: So, for example, if I have a thread that executes the code of the consumer every 2.5 seconds otherwise it is in polling over an event, then I set up the heartbeat_interval_ms to 2750, right?

Comment: Unclear what you mean "executes the code of the consumer", but `max_poll_interval_ms` cannot be longer than the time between 2 polls, so if you have `for msg in consumer` already, then you need to track the time taken within that loop for each message, as well as multiply by whatever `max_poll_records` is for that `consumer` generator (default 500)... The heartbeat should already be on its own background thread, but I'm not exactly sure how `kafka-python` internals work